# Where is UIToolbar.Appearance.TintColor in MonoTouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios6

I am trying to set the color for UIToolbar via UIToolbar.Appearance.TintColor, but that doesn't exist. UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor works just fine. Is there any way to set the tint for toolbars globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a missing feature in MonoTouch, I have fixed this and the next build will contain the fix for it.